# TextBox horizontal scroolbar does not work how I want in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am writing some text into TextBox but I would like to show horizontal scroolbar when I write something longer than width of TextBox. Unfortunatelly, even with setting ScrollBars property to Both or Horizontal program just breaks the line and it looks like writing to new line. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set WordWrap property value to False.

WordWrap indicates whether a multiline text box control automatically wraps words to the beginning of the next line when necessary.

Refer to the following [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Setting the 'WordWrap' property to false should do the trick.